# Settings, formdata or uploader value, swfuploadify is undefined

Tags: settings, uploadify

I'm experimenting with allowing the user to change upload folders, so I'm trying to use 
onUploadStart and the settings to change some values after document.ready and intializing uploadify. But I keep getting this error in the settings function of uploadify

swfuploadify.settings is undefined. using IE11 and the F12 debug

So I suspect that it means that the swf flsh object has not initialized yet, because I can see the values that I set using the debug.

Or am I just missing the boat here on this one?

```
$('[id*="_fu_Preview_Container_Upload_Images"]').uploadify({
        'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': 'fileUploader.ashx?type=images&fP=' + escape(folderPath),
        'buttonClass': 'uploadify-button',
        'buttonText': 'SELECT IMAGE',
        'fileSizeLimit': 0,
        'fileTypeDesc': 'Pictures',
        'fileTypeExts': '*.jpg; *.gif; *.png;',            
        'onUploadStart': function (file) {
            var uploadifyPath = $('[id*="_ddl_PC_UploadP_SelectFolder_Field"] option:selected').val();
            $('[id*="_fu_Preview_Container_Upload_Images"]').uploadify('settings', 'uploader', escape(uploadifyPath), true);
            $('[id*="_fu_Preview_Container_Upload_Images"]').uploadify('settings', 'formdata', {
                'uploadPath': escape(uploadifyPath)
            }, true);                
        },
        'onSWFReady': function () {

        },
        'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after a little thought last night, I decided to remove the event onUploadStart and the uploadify settings.

I wrapped the upload element in an update panel, and set the folder selection to autopostback, knowing that the jquery script would just reload the uploadify button.

So now it works, I can change upload folder destinations.

But what I should really do is take out the update panel, and adjust the scripts.